# Self Hosted Linux Runner doesnt use docker daemon. but docker is installed and works when using ssh to access it

Tags: docker, bitbucket, cicd, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to run docker commands from a bitbucket runner(linux.shell) and even though the docker service is running as shown the command from bitbucket-pipelines.yml doesn't work.

bitbucket-pipelines.yml

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Deploy to production
        runs-on:
          - 'linux.shell'
          - 'self.hosted'
        # trigger: manual  # Uncomment to make this a manual deployment.
        script:
          - echo "Deploying to production environment"
          - sudo lsof -i -P -n
          - systemctl --type=service --state=running
          - docker ps -a
          - chmod +x start-server.sh
          - ./start-server.sh
```

I am expecting to run the docker command for now.
The docker command works fine when executing the runner in the same instance shown in the pic above.
Using a self.hosted linux.shell as described when creating runners in bit-bucket repo

echo $PATH:

> /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

which docker:
/usr/bin/docker

related images:
showing how docker daemon isn't working: https://ibb.co/vQw5X5g
echo $PATH: https://ibb.co/6y2TPRQ

ERROR:

```
+ docker ps -a

Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://localhost:2375. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Comment: could you share the result of echo $PATH in and out of the pipeline

Comment: ssh into the runner and echo $PATH and then put echo $PATH into the pipelines yml and share the result.

Comment: @MichealChoudhary it is the same in both circumstances

Comment: @MichealChoudhary docker is working fine when using putty but using the runner in the same instance doesn't show docker daemon running as in the first pic added

Comment: can you share the error you are getting ?

Comment: added the error and u can see it in this image:  https://ibb.co/vQw5X5g (Sorry, I do not have enough contributions to add image in question) @MichealChoudhary

Comment: can you run the whoami command in pipeline  and share output the result of whoami command ?

Comment: It look like the runner is using a specific user to run your script and that user may not have permissions to talk to /var/run/docker.sock on that system. 
if so, find out the user by running```whoami``` in pipeline and then ssh into the runner and add that specific user to the docker group  ```sudo usermod -aG docker $Runner_User```.
Dont forget to replace $Runner_User with your runner user name

Comment: Sorry, for the late comment but i don't think those solve the problems. I found a workaround using docker in a docker(diad) image for now.

Answer (score 1):

I had this similar issue in a jenkins worker node and adding `sleep 60` worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

By default runner sets DOCKER_HOST to tcp://localhost:2375. If you want use local docker on selfhosted agent just set DOCKER_HOST to empty string. Then your docker executable will user local docker daemon.
It is explained here https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Pipelines-access-docker-host/qaq-p/2184196